# ksmooth function doesn't work with parameters via ellipsis

Tags: r

I am currently working with R due to a course at university, so I am still quite inexperienced.
We use R for exploratory data analysis. In a data analysis we are supposed to apply different regression models to the data and generate the same plots for each. Additionally, we are supposed to play a bit with the parameters for learning purposes. To avoid unattractive 10-20 times copy-pasting I wrote a function that shows the regression function and the parameters for it as an ellipsis (`...`). In this function I call the passed function with the ellipsis as parameter.

```
library("astsa")

data_glob <- globtemp


plot.data.and.reg <- function(data, reg.func, ...){
  model <- reg.func(...)

  par(mfrow = c(1, 2))
  plot(data)
  abline(model, col = "orange", lwd = 3)

  qqnorm(data)

}
```

This works for the simple lm function, but unfortunately not for the ksmooth function.
When I pass this function I get the error message: "numeric y must be supplied. For density estimation use density()".

```
plot.data.and.reg(
  data_g,
  lm,
  list(
    formula = as.formula("data_glob ~ time(data_glob)"),
    data = data_glob
  )
)


plot.data.and.reg(
  data_glob,
  ksmooth,
  list(
    x = as.numeric(time(data_glob)),
    y = as.numeric(data_glob),
    kernel = "box",
    bandwidth = 0.25
  )
)
```

Thereupon I looked at the [source code of `ksmooth`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/ksmooth.R). It shows that this error message occurs because the check "missing(y)" fails. Apparently a problem occurs because I passed the parameters as an ellipsis and it doesn't seem to "unpack".
For simplicity, I wrote a dummy function to test if I can add this "unpack" myself.

```
test.wrapper <- function(func, ...){
    func(...)
}

test <- function(x, y){
  match.call()

  if(missing(y))
    print("Leider hatte ich Recht")

  print(x)
  print(y)
}

test.wrapper(test, list(x = 10, y = 20))
```

Unfortunately I have not found a solution yet.
From Python I know it so that as with kwargs a dictionary can be unpacked with the `**` operator. Is there an equivalent in R? Or how to make sure in R that the parameters from the ellipsis are used correctly?

Since it worked with the lm function without errors I also looked again in [their source code](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/library/stats/R/lm.R) . Unfortunately, with my little experience in R, I can't see exactly where the essential difference is.

Overall, I would attribute the error to the fact that the `ksmooth` function is not yet designed for use with an ellipsis, but I am not sure. How would I need to adjust the `ksmooth` code to make it work with `...`?
(For my Uni task, I will resort to the copy-paste (anti) pattern if in doubt. After searching for so long, I would still be interested in the solution and it may be useful in the future).
Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: By the way, the `as.formula("…")` is redundant. Just write `data_glob ~ time(data_glob)`, it does the exact same thing.

Comment: One more comment, since you mentioned you’re new to R: I recommend not using `.` in identifiers. It’s valid, but it can cause ambiguity with S3 method lookup. A widespread convention is to use underscore instead, e.g. `plot_data_and_reg`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest equivalent of the `*`/`**` splat in Python is the `do.call` function.

However, you don’t need this here. The actual issue is that you’re passing the extra arguments as a *list* rather than individually. Once you flatten the list, it works<sup>1</sup>:

```
plot.data.and.reg(
  data_glob,
  ksmooth,
  x = as.numeric(time(data_glob)),
  y = as.numeric(data_glob),
  kernel = "box",
  bandwidth = 0.25
)
```

I’m actually surprised that it works *with* a list for `lm`; that’s not intentional, it’s essentially an accident caused by how `lm` is currently implemented.

---

<sup>1</sup> I say it “works” because there’s no error and it plots something, but with your example data there’s no visible regression line (`abline` is inappropriate for the output of `ksmooth`), and the smoothing parameters do nothing — the result is identical to the unsmoothed input.

To get this to work, use `lines` instead of `abline`. And as for the smoothing, for your example data a bandwidth of 10 works fine.

Comment: Hello Konrad, thank you very much for your help.
With your advice everything works now, I just had to add a try(lines(.....)) and try(abline(.....)) so that both forms of models could be plotted correctly.
Also thanks for your tip with the function names. There I have probably exactly the wrong habit not adopted from Python. :D